# How to round values of reduceSum in crossfilter?

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm making a map with dc.js and the crossfilter function `reduceSum()` introduces some rounding errors.

simplified example :

```
group = dimension.group().reduceSum(function(e) { return 0.01; });
```

group.all() will contain a value of 32.21000000000216 when the number of records is 3221. It should be 32.21 (the sum of 3221 times 0.01).

You can see the effect I'm talking about here : https://epistat.wiv-isp.be/
(just hover your mouse over the map to see very long decimal numbers)

How can you round the values of a crossfilter group ?

The group has only these methods available:

- all
- dispose
- order
- orderNatural
- reduce
- reduceCount
- reduceSum
- remove
- size
- top

Can you change the value of a group ?
I'm thinking of doing it with a loop but I can't find anything in the docs for changing the value of a group : 
https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference

Comment: You can round on output, but I think the better solution is not to do floating point operations in reducers. Do you have a situation in which this is required?

Comment: @EthanJewett Yes, I don't see an alternative to floating points. I'm computing incidences (sum of records / population). In the end, my map should show 0.1 (units=Cases/100k inhabitants) if I have 1 case and population is 1M. So I don't think I can avoid floating points. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Just store the component counts (cases and total population)? You should generally calculate things like averages and incidences at the time of display and not in the reducers. I think you'll see a nice performance gain and the accumulated floating point arithmetic errors will go away too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround, it's not the a real answer I was looking for, but it's the best I found so far:

I get the closest floating number (closest to the real number) by having the biggest numbers in the data (before dimensions and groups) as possible.
(I'm multiplying `incidence` with `bigMultiplicator=99999999` ; from my tests the bigger the better)

then in the reduceSum I divide by that big number:

```
group = dimension.group().reduceSum(function(e) { return e.incidence / bigMultiplicator; });
```

And I finish by rounding the number in the title display of dc.js:

```
.title(function(d) {
    return d.key + ' : ' + Math.round(d.value * 100)/100 ;
})
```

I hope it helps someone else.

Comment: I'm not really clear what the multiplier does here, since you are already dividing before you take the sum. Isn't it just the rounding in the title function that makes the difference here? Still, thanks for sharing your soliution!

Comment: @Gordon Exactly, I don't understand it either. The number returned in the reduceSum is the same theoretically. But from all my tests it does change something and it can make difference. And no, it isn't only the rounding in the title function, I got the whole number from the JS console.